# Post form, trim value from combo

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a problem. I want to create a form, and i want to post selected value, but i also want to add extra info to each combobox option which i dont want to send.

[image: combobox]

I have that options in combo. And i want to send only value before BuildDate. I can trim that value after send - using
`$rev = $_GET['version']); $temp = explode(" ", $rev); $rev = $temp[0];`
but i would like to not see this in url

Comment: How is this related to `javascript`? If you don't want form values to appear in the URL you should use POST instead of GET

Comment: I want value in url, but I want part of this. I need to have only part of selected combo till first space(without everything after BuildDate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the ID as the `value` attribute in each `option`, that value only will be submitted to the the server, instead of the visible text.

E.g.

```
<select name="yourdropdown">
  <option value="A">A - 100</option>
  <option value="B">B - 200</option>
</select>
```

In that example, if the first option is selected then only `A` is submitted to the server, because that's the `value` of the option.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Also, if you don't want form data to be visible in the URL, you can submit the data via POST (rather than the default GET) - that way the data is transmitted in the body of the request instead.